# Disabling usb driver on Android

Tags: android, usb, webusb

I use webusb for printing on POS printer. And in past I had problems in any systems, but now I have solutions for Windows and Linux. But haven't for Android.

On windows I install Zadig driver.

On linux i make rule `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="3e33", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0130", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n $id:1.0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usblp/unbind && echo -n $id:1.0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbfs/unbind'"` on folder /etc/udev/rules.d/

On Linux and android, I had the same problem that the `usblp` driver did not allow to connect to the printer. But I managed to defeat it on Linux, but I don’t know how on android.

Is it possible to disable the `usblp` driver on android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it is not possible to disable a driver on Android without rooting the device.

The Android SDK provides the ability to request a "forceful" claim of the interface and I have filed https://crbug.com/1099521 with the Chromium project to consider whether to take advantage of it on Android.